# Regexp for phone numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

I'd like to create a regular expression based attribute for my ASP.NET website to check if the specified phone number is valid or not.
It has to let through the patterns like these:

```
+3630 1234 567

06 30 1234 567

0630 1234 567

061 123 456

06 1 123 456
```

So, the most important thing is that the first character can be a '+', but this is not a requirement and after that only numbers and white spaces.

I've tried the following, but no luck with it.

```
public class PhoneNumberAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public PhoneNumberAttribute()
        :base(@"^\+?[0-9 ]")
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex currently accepts an optional `+` sign at the beginning of the string (which is good so far), but only one digit or space. You need to allow more digits/spaces and to do this, you add a quantifier. A good one to use here is the `+` quantifier which means one or more:

```
^\+?[0-9 ]+
```

Now, it will also accept other characters, so add an end of line anchor as well so that the regex checks the whole string:

```
^\+?[0-9 ]+$
```

That should do it. If you have more rules though (such as no consecutive spaces, limited number of digits, etc), the regex will have to be revised.

Comment: Yes, this regex accepts only spaces like `     ` too. though +1 for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks, and how can I change this to accept only one white space char? My best try is: `^\+?[0-9  {1}]+$`

Comment: @tuta4 You mean only one space char in the whole string or one space char at a time?

Comment: For one space char in the whole string, you can use something like `^\+?[0-9]+\s[0-9]+$` (an optional `+` sign, followed by at least one digit, a space and more digits. To allow only one space at a time, you can use `^\+?(?:[0-9]+\s)*[0-9]+$`. For the last one, [here's a demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/eR5lW4). You can edit the regex and the different test inputs.

Comment: Thank you, it is working and the regexp testing website is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try libphonenumber - https://github.com/erezak/libphonenumber-csharp